# CS50P: "timed out while waiting for program to exit"

Tags: python, cs50

I'm trying to solve the "Guessing Game" problem in the Harvard CS50P course (problem set 4). The assignment is to prompt the user for a number x , generate a random number y in the range 1-x, and then have the user guess y, exiting the program when the guess is correct. Any input that's not a number should reprompt the user. It works just fine in the console, but I get the "timed out while waiting for program to exit" error when I check the code with check50. I assume the problem is caused by the while loop in the main() function and tried rephrasing it multiple ways, but I still couldn't fix it.
I copied my code below, any help or tip is appreciated!

check50 output:

:) game.py exists

:) game.py rejects non-numeric level

:) game.py rejects out-of-range level

:) game.py accepts valid level

:) game.py rejects non-numeric guess

:) game.py rejects out-of-range guess

:) game.py outputs "Too large!" when guess is too large

**:( game.py outputs "Just right!" when guess is correct**

**timed out while waiting for program to exit**

:) game.py outputs "Too small!" when guess is too small

```
from random import choice

def main():
    number = choice((list(range(1, get_level() + 1))))    # get random number y from range 1-x
    while True:    # have user guess y
        try:
            guess = int(input("Guess: "))
            if guess > 0:
                if guess < number:
                    print("Too small!")
                elif guess > number:
                    print("Too large!")
                elif guess == number:
                    print("Just right!")
                    break    # break out of loop if guess is correct 
        except ValueError:
            pass


def get_level():
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input("Level: "))
            if level > 0:
                return level
        except ValueError:
            pass


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
then use

sys.exit("Just Right!")
```

instead of

```
print("Just Right!")
break
```

Comment: I can't believe that was the problem, thank you so much! It had been bugging me for such a long time

Answer (score 0):

use
`random.randint()`

instead of
`random.randrange()`